# Calculation permutations unable to solve

Tags: puzzle

Everytime we are trying to solve this expression answer is $48$ or $50$
Can anyone help or guide how to get $49$?
Tried as ($1\cdot 5$) then came $5$... Then added $2$ total came as $7$. Multiple by $3$ and multiply by $2$.. Then added $3$ and $5$ total came as $50$ but unable to reach $49$.. 
[image]

Comment: Can one reuse operations?

Comment: In this case, x3 , x3 , x5 , +2 , +2 would do the job.

Comment: No can't reuse the operation. Only once to be used

Comment: [See this Puzzle SE question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90627/how-to-make-the-number-49)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!

1, +3, x5, +2, x2, +5

Comment: Genius Thanks a lot